# Is there a C# implementation available for Ethereum?

Tags: clients, library, c#, .net

Is there a C# / .NET / Mono implementation available for Ethereum to interact with nodes and/or the blockchain?

Comment: I am just wondering . there is no example to connect with Ethereum pool with c#. I have question and no answering yeat. if I want to connect to Ethereum pool with c# is it RPC connection or what do I need to parsing hash or the pool will assign it to you . I want to understand what is the server behavior

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can try [Nethereum](http://nethereum.com), it's available on [GitHub](https://github.com/Nethereum/Nethereum). Try it on the [Nethereum Playground](http://playground.nethereum.com).

It provides all the generic Web3 functionality to interact with Ethereum like:

- JSON RPC methods
- Contract deployment
- Function call / transaction sending (encoding / decoding parameters)
- Event filtering creation (encoding of parameters / decoding of topics)

Plus much more.

Comment: Its important to note that Nethereum is a web3 implementation in C#, which is fantastic.  Where as the other two mentioned below were attempts to build the entire Ethereum protocol / blockchain in C# which is a much more daunting task.

Comment: I don't believe there is, as of now, a compelling need to create a full ethereum implementation in .net. That was my original intention, and I might do it some time after Casper / Sharding is implemented. Well maybe a front of end of a Dapp using UWP or Xamarin which does not rely on a client like geth or eth.

Comment: But on those scenarios you will want a light client and don't have to download the whole chain.

Comment: Have a look at the Nethermind project, it is a full client with EVM, currently (May 2018) test-syncing with Ropsten and actively developed. You can find the source code at https://github.com/tkstanczak/nethermind

Answer (score 4):

I found these two on GitHub:

[cs-ethereum](https://github.com/etherchain/cs-ethereum) and [Ethereum.NET](https://github.com/CiaranJones/Ethereum.NET).

I haven't tried them out and they look like they've been inactive for quite a while.

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft came up with plugin for smart contract development using Solidity in Visual Studio.

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/96221853-33c4-4531-bdd5-d2ea5acc4799/

You can develop Ethereum smart contracts using Solidity and deploy to Testing network of Ethereum Blockchain, where you will get around 1000 dumy ETH to test your application.

Answer (score 2):

Nethermind is a full .NET Core implementation

You can download Nethermind from here https://github.com/NethermindEth/nethermind/releases
It works with mainnet, rinkeby, goerli, ropsten and private chains.

Give us a shout on gitter if need any guidance
https://gitter.im/nethermindeth/nethermind

Answer (score -2):

Stratis

Native #C

Essentially a copy of ethereum but learning from their mistakes in terms of coding language picked and scalability.

https://stratisplatform.com/

Comment: The website does not appear to mention Ethereum and its relevance is uncertain.